# Ethereum smart contract no function return value

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I'm new to smart contracts and I've deployed this test contract

```
contract test {
    function callme(address dest, uint num, bytes data, uint nonce)
        public
        returns (bytes32 myhash)
    {
        myhash = sha3(dest, num, data, nonce);

        return (myhash);
    }
}
```

I then call test.callme(eth.accounts[0], 10, 0xaaaaa, 1234) expecting it to return the sha3 hash of the passed parameters but there's no return value.

```
> test.callme(eth.accounts[0], 10, 0xaaaaa, 1234)
INFO [12-24|19:35:40] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x694e0e38d0cf8744e62113750339a65f1d5a35cdc634eeb02b93581a926fea1a recipient=0xed712462999f8f68BbF618C3845F4333eDC31cD5
"0x694e0e38d0cf8744e62113750339a65f1d5a35cdc634eeb02b93581a926fea1a"
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I can't reproduce this in remix - the function gives me a proper return value. Not sure what you're working in, but are you sure that command is even supposed to give you a return value? Looks like it's just confirming you sent that call, not necessarily saying there was nothing to be returned.

Comment: I'm using geth console. "are you sure that command is even supposed to give you a return value" - there's "return (myhash)" so that's what I expect to be returned?

Comment: Turns out I was making a dumb mistake trying to reproduce the error - posted a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off - you don't need to name your return value `myhash`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
contract test {
    function callme(address dest, uint num, bytes data, uint nonce)
        public
        constant
        returns (bytes32)
    {
        bytes32 myhash = sha3(dest, num, data, nonce);
        return myhash;
    }
}
```

I also threw in a `constant` keyword since the function isn't planning on changing anything in your contract's storage. It's a small change, but necessary for what you're trying to do.

Including the constant enables you to get a 'return' value, so to speak, because it says that you won't need to be modifying the blockchain - in essence, you're 'reading' the chain, not 'writing' to it.

Imagine a contract that did something like this:

```
contract test {

    uint example;

    function callme()
        public
        returns (uint)
    {
        example = example + 1;
        return example;
    }
}
```

The transaction we send to `callme` actually has to be executed  **before**  we return the value (since we're modifying the blockchain). Therefore, we can't really return the final value instantly (and we instead return information about the transaction), since we have to wait for the blockchain to be updated first.

Comment: thank you! this makes more sense now. regarding the second part of your answer, how would I go about getting the 'example' value after the blockchain has been updated? (all I have is a transaction hash)

Comment: AFAIK, you can't (at least with Solidity in its current state).